# Database Mail Attachment file .xlsx is invalid in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, email

I want to send mail using SQL Server mail. My code is like this:

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'SPMS-Mail',
        @recipients = 'e.akbar1367@gmail.com',
        @subject = 'hi',
        @body = 'This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.',
        @file_attachments='D:\a.xlsx'
```

But I get this error :

> Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
>   Attachment file D:\a.xlsx is invalid.

Comment: Make sure that the Excel sheet is on the D: Drive of your SQL server not your workstation from which you are connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Account (through which SQL Server service is running) having access to your `D` drive. Add the account to access the file. Because, `sp_send_dbmail` runs through the same account.

If account not having permission to D drive. **For Testing,** create a folder under D drive and grant permission to the SQL Service account to it (under security of that folder) and place the file there and use that path in your T-SQL code.

Answer (score -2):

What is D:\ ?

Is it a server location?

If so, you might need

```
@file_attachments='\\myservername\d$\a.xlsx'
```

Comment: D is my local drive

Comment: now i get this Attachment file F:\SPMS-SHARE\share\FILE NAHAEI HISTORY PAYANDAN\a.xlsx is invalid.

Comment: I'd give you a solution but there are some losers here who voted down my original answer.  Sorry about that, welcome to the world of "I live at home with mom" developers.